# Why do some of the password stop working

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I have made a .Net application and have used the built-in form authentication. There are about 200 users. In about 2 months time, 6 user passwords have suddenly stopped working. I have deleted the users and registered them again. Does anyone know if there is a glitch somewhere, or something else that made the password change or get ruined?

I'm using Ms SQL 2008 r2 server, and Visual Studio 2010.

EDIT:
I'm sorry for not being more spesific. I asked for help because didn't know what to look for, because this is somehow new to me.
Web.config is showing: SqlMembershipProvider, and I think it's as easy that maxInvalidPasswordAttempts is set too low. All i hear from users is that it suddenly stops working...

Thanks Arran

Comment: Glitch in the matrix? Who knows? Do they have expiry dates? What membership provider do you use, the default one with ASP.NET? What extra logic do you implement ontop of this? How are the passwords stored? TL:DR; Hard to tell without some concrete examples & information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was maxInvalidPasswordAttempts that was set too low, and the users was locked out. There is a field in the aspnet_Membership table, called IsLockedOut, that is set to true.

DevNewbie